# Why is not saved cookies in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a website where I show a temporary message to the user. This message should behave as follows:

- If an user is scrolling, message disappears - `slideUp()`.
- If an user clicks on the close button, set css class `.closed` and stored in the cookie from the buzz shut that after changing to another page again showed up this panel.

I need to store a cookie when an user clicks on the close button (`.info-close`) panel to update again after this panel does not show.

There is my problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbsmbkfm/4/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var $close = $("#info-panel .info-close");
    var $info_panel = $("#info-panel");
    var $site_main = $(".site-main");
    
    $close.click(function(){
        $info_panel.slideUp();
        $info_panel.addClass("closed");
        // set cookie
        document.cookie = "1";
        // save cookie to "$yes_closed"
        var $yes_closed = document.cookie;
    });
    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // if panel has class closed, after click on "X" > dont open
        // or if in cookie "$yes_closed" is save "1" > dont open
        if ($info_panel.hasClass("closed")) {
            $info_panel.hide();
        } else {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $info_panel.slideUp();
            } else {
                $info_panel.slideDown();
            }
        }
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
#info-panel {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background: yellow;
}

.info-close {
    padding: 5px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/><br/><br/>

<div id="info-panel">
  <div class="info-text">You are reading documentation for version 9.0.1. Documentation for earlier versions is available as pdfs here.</div>
  <div class="info-close">X</div>
 </div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<p>"Hello my friend"</p>
```

Comment: Dont votedown or flag this post if you are dont write nothing into anwsers or comments. Thx a lot only votedown users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
It is because the cookie is not set properly. You need to add a cookie name and assign value to it. On page load do check if the cookie is set. Based on that show the message.

I have your code fixed here in the jsfiddle. Take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssbiswal1987/9bhnyxwn/
```

Comment: For how long they are stored?

Comment: It depends on the number of years you add.

now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 2);

Here I added 2 years

Comment: Note: You can also use window.localstorage as well for this but then it does not support ie7

Please mark the answer as accepted if it serve to purpose.

Comment: If I want for 24hours I set this `now.setDate(1);`

Comment: yes in the expression now.setFullYear there is a 2 that is the number of years